# RecyclerView Item Size changing while scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-imageview

When first time `recyclerView` Load It will show all proper. but after scrolling, layout item size changed.

[image]

this is my `item_layout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/item_border"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/item_margin_2">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageProduct"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textProductTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/title_textSize"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageProduct"
        tools:text="TubeLight" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textProductDetailSort"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/detail_textSize"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textProductTitle"
        tools:text="warranty: 100 days" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linerCartItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textProductDetailSort">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonRemove"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/item_border_small"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_outline_remove_24"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textNumberItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
            android:textSize="@dimen/detail_small_textSize"
            android:padding="@dimen/item_padding"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/item_margin_3"
            android:text="0"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonAdd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/item_border_small"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewProductPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/linerCartItem"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/item_margin"
        android:text="@string/title_price"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

this is `adapter class`

```
class ProductListAdapter(context: Context, private val cellClickListener: HomeFragment) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    interface CellClickListener {
        fun onCellClickListener(productModel: ProductModel)
        fun onNextClicked()
        fun onPrevClicked()
        fun onAddClicked(productId: String): Int
        fun onRemoveClicked(productId: String): Int
    }

    val FOOTER_TYPE : Int = 1
    val HEADER_TYPE : Int = 2
    var context : Context = context

    private var listOfProducts = listOf<ProductModel>()


    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {

         if (position ==  listOfProducts.size) {

             return FOOTER_TYPE
         }
//         else if(position == 0){
//            return HEADER_TYPE
//         }
        return 0

    }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        if (viewType == FOOTER_TYPE){
            return ProductListViewHolderFooter(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                    R.layout.item_product_footer,
                    parent, false
                )
            )
        }else if(viewType == HEADER_TYPE){
            return ProductListViewHolderHeader(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                    R.layout.item_product_header,
                    parent, false
                )
            )
        }
        else{
            return ProductListViewHolder(
                context,
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                    R.layout.item_product,
                    parent,
                    false
                )
            )
        }

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = listOfProducts.size + 1

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        try {
            if (viewHolder is ProductListViewHolder) {
                val vh: ProductListViewHolder = viewHolder as ProductListViewHolder
                vh.bindView(listOfProducts[position], cellClickListener)

            } else if (viewHolder is ProductListViewHolderFooter) {
                val vh: ProductListViewHolderFooter = viewHolder as ProductListViewHolderFooter
                vh.bindViewFooter(listOfProducts[position], cellClickListener)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }


    }

    fun setProductList(listOfProducts: List<ProductModel>) {

        this.listOfProducts = listOfProducts
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

and this is `holder`

```
class ProductListViewHolder(context: Context,itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

   
    var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(utils.PREFERENCE_FILE_NAME,
        Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
  

    fun bindView(productModel: ProductModel, cellClickListener: HomeFragment) {
        itemView.textProductTitle.text = productModel.productTitle
        itemView.textProductDetailSort.text = productModel.productDetailSort


        itemView.textViewProductPrice.text = context.getString(R.string.title_price) + ": " + productModel.price

       
        itemView.textNumberItem.text = cart

        Glide.with(itemView.context).load(productModel.productImageUrl!!).into(itemView.imageProduct)

         itemView.imageProduct.setOnClickListener{
             cellClickListener.onCellClickListener(productModel)
         }

         itemView.buttonRemove.setOnClickListener {
             val cart = cellClickListener.onRemoveClicked(productModel.productId)
             itemView.textNumberItem.text = cart.toString()
         }

         itemView.buttonAdd.setOnClickListener {
             val cart = cellClickListener.onAddClicked(productModel.productId)
             itemView.textNumberItem.text = cart.toString()
         }

    }


}
```

Comment: What is the desired one? The left item with more gaps at the top and bottom of the image view or the right one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem caused by not having any control over the height of the `ImageView` which leads to varying sizes in the view-recycling process. To fix this issue, you need to apply a bit of change in the `imageProduct` attributes.

First, as you bound the `imageProduct`'s start and end to the parent's start and end, you should set the view width to `0dp` to be sure it fills the whole space.

Second, set `adjustViewBounds` attribute to `true`. It leads to adjusting the `ImageView` bounds to preserve the aspect ratio of its drawable.

Third, set `layout_constrainedHeight` attribute to `true`. It ensures that the height of the view remains constrained and also lets view height remains as `wrap_content`.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageProduct"
    android:layout_width="0dp"                      // 1
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"                 // 2
    app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"             // 3
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

In addition, if you want to always show the image with a specific aspect ratio, you'd be able to achieve it by changing the height to `0dp` also defining the ratio using `layout_constraintDimensionRatio` attribute, like the following:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageProduct"
    android:layout_width="0dp"                     
    android:layout_height="0dp"                     // setting the height constrainted
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"      
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"       // to show as a square  
    app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"             
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Comment: thanks.. you save my day.. layout is beautifully managed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to call glide clear `Glide.with(itemView.context).clear(itemView.imageProduct)`
at top of
`Glide.with(itemView.context).load(productModel.productImageUrl!!).into(itemView.imageProduct)`